# How to apply a function to multiple columns to create multiple new columns in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, rstudio, sequence

I've this list of sequences **aqi_range** and a dataframe **df**:

```
aqi_range = list(0:50,51:100,101:250)
```

**df**

```
   PM10_mean PM10_min PM10_max PM2.5_mean PM2.5_min PM2.5_max
 1      85.6        3      264       75.7         3       240
 2     105.         6      243       76.4         3       191
 3      95.8       19      287       48.4         8       134
 4      85.5       50      166       64.8        32       103
 5      55.9       24      117       46.7        19        77
 6      37.5        6      116       31.3         3        87
 7      26          5       69       15.5         3        49
 8      82.3       34      169       49.6        25       120
 9      170        68      272       133         67       201
10      254       189      323       226        173       269
```

Now I've created these two pretty simple functions that i want to apply to this dataframe to calculate the **AQI=Air Quality Index** for each pollutant.

```
#a = column from a dataframe  **PM10_mean, PM2.5_mean**
#b = list of sequences defined above
min_max_diff <- function(a,b){
        for (i in b){
          if (a %in% i){
           min_val = min(i)
           max_val = max(i)
           return (max_val - min_val)
        }}}

#a = column from a dataframe  **PM10_mean, PM2.5_mean**
#b = list of sequences defined above
c_low <- function(a,b){
      for (i in b){
       if (a %in% i){
        min_val = min(i)
        return(min_val)
          } 
      }}
```

**Basically the first function "min_max_diff" takes the value of column df$PM10_mean / df$PM2.5_mean and check for it in the list "aqi_range" and then returns a certain value (difference of min and max value of the sequence in which it's available). Similarly the second function "c_low" just returns the minimum value of the sequence.**

I want to apply this kind of manipulation (formula defined below) to PM10_mean column to create new columns PM10_AQI:

```
df$PM10_AQI  = min_max_diff(df$PM10_mean,aqi_range) / (df$PM10_max - df$PM10_min) / * (df$PM10_mean -  df$PM10_min) + c_low(df$PM10_mean,aqi_range)
```

I hope it explains it properly.

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(df)`?

Comment: `diff` is a `base R` function.  Please use another name

Comment: it's a pretty big dataframe. @IceCreamToucan

Comment: I've added the first 10 rows of the dataset. Can you please try to use the functions that i've defined ?? @IceCreamToucan

Comment: I've added in bold letters what i want to achieve with those two functions. @IceCreamToucan

Comment: Can you please check your function `min_max_diff(df$PM10_mean,aqi_range) / (df$PM10_max - df$PM10_min) / (df$PM10_mean -  df$PM10_min) + c_low(df$PM10_mean,aqi_range)` gives me `numeric(0)`

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a function, there i was just trying to explain the maipulation that need to be done to calculate the AQI.  I want to apply those two functions(min_max_diff & c_low ) to column PM10_mean and have to employ PM10_max and PM10_min columns as well for the manipulations to get AQI for PM10. I've multiple Pollutants in the data, so i would need to apply same approach on multiple columns.

Comment: This manipulation needs to be done  """ min_max_diff(df$PM10_mean,aqi_range) / (df$PM10_max - df$PM10_min) / (df$PM10_mean - df$PM10_min) + c_low(df$PM10_mean,aqi_range) """ to calculate the AQI.  I hope i'm explaining it properly-

Comment: The first value in `PM10_mean` is `85.6` and you are checking for `if (a %in% i)` in the function. None of the values in `aqi_range` satisfies this criterion so `a %in% i` will never be true. Note that `aqi_range` has all integers whereas numbers in `PM10_mean` are decimals and you are performing an exact match. Do you want to check if the numbers are in range or something ? Also in the last part where you have shared data I am assuming your input has only two columns `PM10_mean` and `PM2.5_mean`, rest of them are your expected output columns.

Comment: Yes it's my mistake, i do want to check if the number in the range or not and then perform the manipulations onn that basis. i've all these columns in the data, i just have to calculate the the column "PM10_AQI and PM2.5_AQI" on these of existing columns. @RonakShah

Comment: I am confused about your input as well as the expected output. I see multiple sample of input data. Can you clear up your post to keep only relevant information ? Show clearly your input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is just how to compute the given transformation to several columns in a data frame, you could write a for loop, construct the name of each variable involved in the transformation using string transformation functions (in this case `sub()` is useful), and refer to the columns in the data frame using the `[` notation (as opposed to the `$` notation --since the `[` notation accepts strings to specify columns).

Following I show an example of such code with a small sample data with 3 observations:

*(note that I modified the definition of the AQI range values (now I just define the breaks where the range changes --assuming they are all integers), and your functions `min_max_diff()` and `c_low()` which are collapsed into one single function returning the min and max values of the AQI range where the values are found --again this assumes that the AQI values are integer values)*

```
# Definition of the AQI ranges (which are assumed to be based on integer values)
# Note that if the number of AQI ranges is k, the number of breaks is k+1
# Each break value defines the minimum of the range
# The maximum of each range is computed as the "minimum of the NEXT range" - 1
# (again this assumes integer values in AQI ranges)
# The values (e.g. PM10_mean) whose AQI range is searched for are assumed
# to NOT be larger than or equal to the largest break value.
aqi_range_breaks = c(0, 51, 101, 251)

# Example data (top 3 rows of the data frame you provided)
df = data.frame(PM10_mean=c(85.6, 105.0, 95.8),
                PM10_min=c(3, 6, 19),
                PM10_max=c(264, 243, 287),
                PM2.5_mean=c(75.7, 76.4, 48.4),
                PM2.5_min=c(3, 3, 8),
                PM2.5_max=c(240, 191, 134))

# Function that returns the minimum and maximum AQI values
# of the AQI range where the given values are found
# `values`: array of values that are searched for in the AQI ranges
# defined by the second parameter.
# `aqi_range_breaks`: breaks defining the minimum values of each AQI range
# plus one last value defining a value never attained by `values`.
# (all values in this parameter defining the AQI ranges are assumed integer values)
find_aqi_range_min_max <- function(values, aqi_range_breaks){
  aqi_range_groups = findInterval(values, aqi_range_breaks)
  return( list(min=aqi_range_breaks[aqi_range_groups],
               max=aqi_range_breaks[aqi_range_groups + 1] - 1))
}

# Run the variable transformation on the selected `_mean` columns
vars_mean = c("PM10_mean", "PM2.5_mean")
for (vmean in vars_mean) {
  vmin = sub("_mean$", "_min", vmean)
  vmax = sub("_mean$", "_max", vmean)
  vaqi = sub("_mean$", "_AQI", vmean)
  aqi_range_min_max = find_aqi_range_min_max(df[,vmean], aqi_range_breaks)
  df[,vaqi] = (aqi_range_min_max$max - aqi_range_min_max$min) / 
              (df[,vmax] - df[,vmin]) / (df[,vmean] -  df[,vmin]) +
              aqi_range_min_max$min
}
```

Note how the `findInterval()` function has been used to find the range where *an array of values* fall. That was the key to make your transformation work for a data frame column.

The expected output of this process is:

```
  PM10_mean PM10_min PM10_max PM2.5_mean PM2.5_min PM2.5_max  PM10_AQI    PM2.5_AQI
1      85.6        3      264       75.7         3       240  51.00227 51.002843893
2     105.0        6      243       76.4         3       191 101.00635 51.003550930
3      95.8       19      287       48.4         8       134  51.00238  0.009822411
```

Please check the formula that computes AQI because you had a syntax error in it (look for `/ *`, which I have replaced with `/` in the formula in my code).

Note that the use of `$` in the regular expression used in `sub()` to match the string `"_mean"` is used to replace the `"_mean"` string only when it occurs at the end of the variable name.

Comment: I tried this and it gave me this error:   "Error in Ops.data.frame(min_max_diff(y[, vmean], aqi_range)/(y[, vmax] -  : 
  ‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames"

Comment: The functions "min_max_diff() and c_low()" work fine if give them any random number as an input , but isn't seems to be working on a dataframe columns. Any advise, how i can solve this ?

Comment: @astroluv I have just edited the answer so that now the transformation works with data frame columns. The key point was the use of the `findInterval()` function.
Note how I redefined the AQI ranges (now defined simply as breaks), which, as noted, assumes that the values in the AQI ranges are all integer.
As explained in the edit, I also simplified the two functions into a single function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked for me and your comments helped alot in understanding the root cause.