# How to generate new columns from the existing multiple columns partially according to their names in r?

Tags: r

I would like to generated new columns from the existing multiple columns according to their names.
Here is some data that approximates my tables.

```
id <- c("s001", "s002", "s003", "s004", "s005", "s006", "s007", "s008", "s009")
group <- c(0,1,2,1,2,0,0,1,2)
lh_apple_thickness <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
lh_banana_thickness <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17)
lh_orange_thickness <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)
rh_apple_thickness <- c(3,7,2,1,5,4,2,6,11)
rh_banana_thickness <- c(2,4,5,4,2,4,3,1,5)
rh_orange_thickness <- c(3,6,2,4,5,6,2,5,4)
lh_apple_volume <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
lh_banana_volume <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17)
lh_orange_volume <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)
rh_apple_volume <- c(3,7,2,1,5,4,2,6,11)
rh_banana_volume <- c(2,4,5,4,2,4,3,1,5)
rh_orange_volume <- c(3,6,2,4,5,6,2,5,4)
df <- data.frame(id,group,lh_apple_thickness,lh_banana_thickness,lh_orange_thickness,rh_apple_thickness,rh_banana_thickness,rh_orange_thickness,lh_apple_volume,lh_banana_volume,lh_orange_volume,rh_apple_volume,rh_banana_volume,rh_orange_volume)
df$group <- as.factor(df$group)
```

These data have three group levels and two kinds of measures (thickness and volume).

I would like **to calculate an asymmetric index for each item per measure in each group using this formula**: `index = (L - R)/(L + R)`.

Take apple as an example, the specific formula:
`index for thickness = (lh_apple_thickness - rh_apple_thickness)/(lh_apple_thickness + right_apple_thickness)`,
`index for volume = (lh_apple_volume - rh_apple_volume)/(lh_apple_volume + right_apple_volume)`. I would like to generate these two kinds of indices for all items including apple, banana and orange. By the way, **in my real data, I have almost 400 columns to be calculated**. And **there are also some other columns with underline (`_`) in their names, which were not needed to be calculated**.

I have tried to achieve my goal based on answers in these two questions ([Calculate row means based on (partial) matching column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397210/calculate-row-means-based-on-partial-matching-column-names) and [How to apply a function to multiple columns to create multiple new columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585724/how-to-apply-a-function-to-multiple-columns-to-create-multiple-new-columns-in-r)), but it still does not work.

So, my question is **how to generate new columns from the existing multiple columns partially according to their names** and **add these new columns into the original data frame at the same time**?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be first generating all combinations of fruits and measures and then creating the desired index for each combination possible. Consider this function:

```
gen_index <- function(df, ...) {
  nms <- purrr::cross(list(...))
  nms <- vapply(nms, function(x) paste0(as.character(x), collapse = "_"), character(1L))
  lh <- paste0("lh_", nms)
  rh <- paste0("rh_", nms)
  res <- paste0(nms, "_index")
  Reduce(function(d, i) {
    `[[<-`(d, res[[i]], value = (d[[lh[[i]]]] - d[[rh[[i]]]]) / (d[[lh[[i]]]] + d[[rh[[i]]]]))
  }, seq_along(nms), df)
}
```

You can then do this:

```
gen_index(df, c("apple", "banana", "orange"), c("thickness", "volume"))
```

which gives you

```
    id group lh_apple_thickness lh_banana_thickness lh_orange_thickness rh_apple_thickness rh_banana_thickness rh_orange_thickness lh_apple_volume lh_banana_volume
1 s001     0                  1                   1                   2                  3                   2                   3               1                1
2 s002     1                  2                   3                   4                  7                   4                   6               2                3
3 s003     2                  3                   5                   6                  2                   5                   2               3                5
4 s004     1                  4                   7                   8                  1                   4                   4               4                7
5 s005     2                  5                   9                  10                  5                   2                   5               5                9
6 s006     0                  6                  11                  12                  4                   4                   6               6               11
7 s007     0                  7                  13                  14                  2                   3                   2               7               13
8 s008     1                  8                  15                  16                  6                   1                   5               8               15
9 s009     2                  9                  17                  18                 11                   5                   4               9               17
  lh_orange_volume rh_apple_volume rh_banana_volume rh_orange_volume apple_thickness_index banana_thickness_index orange_thickness_index apple_volume_index
1                2               3                2                3            -0.5000000             -0.3333333             -0.2000000         -0.5000000
2                4               7                4                6            -0.5555556             -0.1428571             -0.2000000         -0.5555556
3                6               2                5                2             0.2000000              0.0000000              0.5000000          0.2000000
4                8               1                4                4             0.6000000              0.2727273              0.3333333          0.6000000
5               10               5                2                5             0.0000000              0.6363636              0.3333333          0.0000000
6               12               4                4                6             0.2000000              0.4666667              0.3333333          0.2000000
7               14               2                3                2             0.5555556              0.6250000              0.7500000          0.5555556
8               16               6                1                5             0.1428571              0.8750000              0.5238095          0.1428571
9               18              11                5                4            -0.1000000              0.5454545              0.6363636         -0.1000000
  banana_volume_index orange_volume_index
1          -0.3333333          -0.2000000
2          -0.1428571          -0.2000000
3           0.0000000           0.5000000
4           0.2727273           0.3333333
5           0.6363636           0.3333333
6           0.4666667           0.3333333
7           0.6250000           0.7500000
8           0.8750000           0.5238095
9           0.5454545           0.6363636
```

If you only want to calculate that index for a subset of your dataframe:

```
gen_index(df, c("apple", "banana"), "thickness")
```

Output

```
    id group lh_apple_thickness lh_banana_thickness lh_orange_thickness rh_apple_thickness rh_banana_thickness rh_orange_thickness lh_apple_volume lh_banana_volume
1 s001     0                  1                   1                   2                  3                   2                   3               1                1
2 s002     1                  2                   3                   4                  7                   4                   6               2                3
3 s003     2                  3                   5                   6                  2                   5                   2               3                5
4 s004     1                  4                   7                   8                  1                   4                   4               4                7
5 s005     2                  5                   9                  10                  5                   2                   5               5                9
6 s006     0                  6                  11                  12                  4                   4                   6               6               11
7 s007     0                  7                  13                  14                  2                   3                   2               7               13
8 s008     1                  8                  15                  16                  6                   1                   5               8               15
9 s009     2                  9                  17                  18                 11                   5                   4               9               17
  lh_orange_volume rh_apple_volume rh_banana_volume rh_orange_volume apple_thickness_index banana_thickness_index
1                2               3                2                3            -0.5000000             -0.3333333
2                4               7                4                6            -0.5555556             -0.1428571
3                6               2                5                2             0.2000000              0.0000000
4                8               1                4                4             0.6000000              0.2727273
5               10               5                2                5             0.0000000              0.6363636
6               12               4                4                6             0.2000000              0.4666667
7               14               2                3                2             0.5555556              0.6250000
8               16               6                1                5             0.1428571              0.8750000
9               18              11                5                4            -0.1000000              0.5454545
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do is to 'tidy' up the data first. E.g. having 1 row per fruit-combination

I could only do this in two steps, 1 for lh and one for rh, im sure there is a smarter way

```
df_lh <- df %>% dplyr::select(id, group, grep("^lh", names(.))) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = 3:ncol(.),
    names_to = "lh", values_to = "lh_values")
df_rh <- df %>% dplyr::select(id, group, grep("^rh", names(.))) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = 3:ncol(.),
    names_to = "rh", values_to = "rh_values")

df_result <- df_lh %>% dplyr::left_join(df_rh, by = c("id", "group")) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(result = (lh_values - rh_values) / (lh_values + rh_values))
```

If you only want same-fruit combinations, then filter out the mixed-fruit combinations

```
df_result %>% dplyr::filter(stringr::str_extract(lh, "_(.)*_") == stringr::str_extract(rh, "_(.)*_"))
```

edit

putting the data back into wide format.

I'll assume that you only want to compare fruits to fruits and atributes  to attributes (volume, thickness etc)

```
df_result_wide <- df_result %>% 
  dplyr::filter(stringr::str_extract(lh, "_(.)*_") == 
stringr::str_extract(rh, "_(.)*_"),
            stringr::str_extract(lh, "_(.)*$") == stringr::str_extract(rh,"_(.)*$")) %>% 
 tidyr::pivot_wider(
  id_cols = c("id", "group"), names_from = c("lh", "rh"), values_from = 
c("result"))
```

finally putting the result together with the original data

```
df_final <- df %>% dplyr::left_join(df_result_wide, by = c("id", "group"))
```

Comment: Many thanks, it does work. However, I need add these new columns in the original data frame. I would edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Hi Ella_may, I've added a bit of code to put the data back into wide-format and join with the original data. let me know if it works. Another thing: In my opinion it is just easier to work in long format. You might save yourself trouble in the long run if you convert. good luck :)

Comment: Hi Jagge, thank you so much. I have some other columns with `_` in their names. It is largely that these columns lead to errors. Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but only if the l-column always comes before the respective r-column of the same category (otherwise you would have to change a bit in the code):

> ```
> categories <- colnames(df) %>% gsub("^.._","",.) %>% {.[grepl("_",.)]} 
> df2 <- lapply(categories, function(x) df[,grepl(x,colnames(df))]) %>% 
>   sapply(function(x) rbind(apply(x,1,function(y) (y[1]-y[2])/(y[1]+y[2]))) ) %>% 
>   `colnames<-`(categories)
> df3 <- cbind(df, df2)
> ```

first I generate a vector with the categories without rh or lh, simple gsub-task, and then a grepl to only get the category column names and not "id" and "group" (using the circumstance that those two columns don't contain a "_")

then some apply-stuff to avoid for loops. The lapply generates a list where each item has the columns that match a single category. The sapply then takes these columns and applies your formula to each row (here, the y[1] and y[2] are the reason this only works when lh is always before rh); the result is directly rbind-ed. That returns a data.frame without column names, so they are provided from the categories vector.

Comment: Many thanks. This works for the example. Actually, my real data have some other columns with '_' and I just got error when applying to the real data. Maybe need to delete other columns with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is base R option using `lapply` extracting `unique_fruits` and `unique_measure` from the data so it can be applied to any number of fruits as well any number of measure.

```
unique_fruits <- unique(sub('.*_(.*)_.*', '\\1', names(df)[-c(1, 2)]))
unique_fruits
#[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange"
unique_measure <- unique(sub('.*_', '', names(df)[-c(1, 2)]))
unique_measure
#[1] "thickness" "volume"   

cbind(df, do.call(cbind, lapply(unique_fruits, function(x) {
  setNames(do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(unique_measure, function(y) {
    lhs <- sprintf('lh_%s_%s', x, y)
    rhs <- sprintf('rh_%s_%s', x, y)
    (df[[lhs]] - df[[rhs]])/(df[[lhs]] + df[[rhs]])
  })), paste0('index_', unique_measure))
}))) -> result
```